# What is the difference between lscpu Socket and networking Socket?

Tags: socket

`lscpu` output looks like-

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1200.093
BogoMIPS:              3392.08
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

The output shows the pc has 1 socket and 2 cores per socket. Probably this socket is not networking socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right! The socket in `lscpu`’s output refers to the physical socket which the processor package sits in, on the motherboard; a networking socket typically refers to [BSD sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

Answer (score 0):

lscpu does not list networking sockets. As per the above output there is 1 socket and it has 2 cores and each core has 2 CPUs.